# How to copy list from class to another class in Windows Phone 8.1 with Parsing Pages

Tags: c#, list, parsing, windows-phone-8.1

I want to copy items from list_data in PurePcData to MainPage -> list_PurePc.

**MainPage.cs:**

```
public List<PurePcData> list_PurePc = new List<PurePcData>();

public MainPage()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    this.NavigationCacheMode = NavigationCacheMode.Required;
    PurePcData purePc = new PurePcData();
}
```

**PurePcData.cs:**

```
public class PurePcData
{
    private string url = "http://www....";
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public BitmapImage Image { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }

    public List<PurePcData> list_data = new List<PurePcData>();
    public MainPage main;

    public PurePcData()
    {
        Parsing();
    }

    public PurePcData(string title, BitmapImage image, string content)
    {
        Title = title;
        Image = image;
        Content = content;
    }


    private async void Parsing()
    {
        try
        {
            string url_string;
            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                url_string = await client.GetStringAsync(new Uri(url));
            }

            HtmlDocument htmlDocument = new HtmlDocument();
            htmlDocument.LoadHtml(url_string);

            HtmlNode node = htmlDocument.DocumentNode.Descendants("div").FirstOrDefault(o => o.GetAttributeValue("class", null) == "latest_items");
            HtmlNodeCollection nodeCollection = node.ChildNodes;

            foreach (HtmlNode itemNode in nodeCollection)
            {

                var titleAndImage = itemNode.Descendants("a").FirstOrDefault(x => x.GetAttributeValue("class", null) == "ni_image");
                if (titleAndImage != null)
                {
                    var attributes = titleAndImage.Descendants("img").FirstOrDefault(x => x.GetAttributeValue("alt", "") != null);
                    var title = attributes.Attributes["alt"].Value;
                    var image = attributes.Attributes["src"].Value;

                    list_data.Add(new PurePcData(title, new BitmapImage(new Uri(image)), ""));

                }
            }
            //IN THIS PLACE, I want Send DATA FROM list_data to list_PurePc in MainPage

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            MessageDialog msgDialog = new MessageDialog(e.Message);
            msgDialog.ShowAsync();
        }
    }
```

I tried to do this using static lists, objects. Nothing worked.

Please help me with this problem.

Comment: Why wouldn't you pass it via constructor?

Comment: If you're navigating between pages, you can call `Frame.Navigate(typeof(MyPage), list_PurePc)`.  Within the `OnNavigatedTo()` method of the page you're navigating to (`MyPage` in this example), you can get the list with `List<PurePcData> list = (PurePcData)e.Argument`.  __If you're not navigating between pages, pass the list through your page constructor, as @JanesAbouChleih said.__

Answer (score 0):

I found problem, this is async method. When client download html code to "url_string" field, method continue working. Is there any way, that the method waited until the download data? or transform method to nonasync ?